# Is there shorthand in Tcl to get a sequential array of numbers?

Tags: tcl

For example, in Perl, to get a sequential array of numbers from 1 to 10, you could simply do:

```
@myArray = (1 .. 10);
```

The two periods serve as shorthand for this operations instead of making a for loop or writing the whole thing out manually. Other languages I've used have something similar also.

Does a similar shorthand exist in Tcl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite this one, but

```
% package require struct::list
1.6.1
% struct::list iota 10
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Also search [this](http://wiki.tcl.tk/819) for the "iota" keyword to see how this can be done using a one-liner.

Comment: Alright! Not perfect, but better than doing a loop each time. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @Nate, Tcl's approach has its upsides: you can create as many of such convenient commands as you wish, and they will all look no different from "native" tools. And I wouldn't take (X...Y) notation for granted to be built into the language's syntax otherwise we could also think of factorial literals for instance and whatnot ;-)

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. Good points. I am new to programming so I haven't arrived at such concepts/understandings.

Answer (score 6):

You can define the method:

```
proc fillArray {a b} {
    eval return \[list $a [string repeat "\[incr a\] " [incr b -$a]]\]
}
```

And use it as:

```
set myArray [fillArray 1 10]
```

---

You even can beautify the call of procedure to make it look as in perl. For that just redefine `unknown` procedure:

```
rename unknown __unknown
proc unknown {args} {
  if {[llength $args] == 3} {
    lassign $args a op b
    if {[string is integer $a] && $op == ".." && [string is integer $b]} {
      return [fillArray $a $b]
    }
  }
  return [uplevel __unknown {*}$args]
}
```

After that you can write just simple as:

```
set myArray [1 .. 10]
```

:)

Comment: In your first example, `subst "$a[string repeat { [incr a]} [incr b -$a]]"` is a shorter procedure body…

Answer (score 5):

With the exception of expressions (which are their own little language) Tcl has no operators and is always a strictly prefix-driven language. This means that there isn't such a convenient shorthand for doing loops. On the other hand, there's nothing particularly special about Tcl's standard commands (apart from some minor efficiency details that don't matter here) so making your own is no problem:

```
proc .. {from to} {
    if {$from >= $to} {
        for {set i $from} {$i <= $to} {incr i}    {lappend out $i}
    } else {
        for {set i $from} {$i >= $to} {incr i -1} {lappend out $i}
    }
    return $out
}

puts [.. 1 10];   # --> “1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10”
```

You can fake infix operators by using an unknown handler (as in GrAnd's answer) but that's really quite slow by comparison with the above.

Answer (score 1):

No, a similar shorthand does not exist in tcl.

If you really want shorthand, you can create your own command that looks almost the same. For example:

```
proc : {start ignore end} {
    set result []
    for {set i $start} {$i <= $end} {incr i} {
        lappend result $i
    }
    return $result
}

puts "from 1 to 10: [: 1 .. 10]"
```

Comment: Unfortunate, but that's the nature of the tcl beast. Thanks!

Comment: @Nate: think of it not as a shortcoming, but as a strength. You can easily write your own command to do this quite easily.