# How do I efficiently (mem/time) modify all elelements of a list in Tcl?

Tags: performance, dictionary, tcl, benchmarking, list-comprehension

To operate on each element of a list, returning a modified list various languages have explicit constructs.

In Perl there's map:

```
perl -e 'my @a = (1..4); print join(q( ), map { $_ * $_ } @a)'
1 4 9 16
```

In Python there're list comprehensions:

```
>>> a = (1,2,3,4)
>>> [el*el for el in a]
[1, 4, 9, 16]
```

What's the most efficient way to do this in Tcl?
I can come up with the usual foreach loop.

```
set l {}
foreach i {1 2 3 4} {
    lappend l [expr $i * $i]
}
puts $l
1 4 9 16
```

Is this the fastest way?

Regarding mem efficiency this builds up a second list, one by one. If I don't need the list permanently is there a more efficient way?

And, finally, is there something that's shorter?
I couldn't find infos here or in the http://wiki.tcl.tk

Answer:

As Donal Fellows has answered, most importantly for speed tests, things should be wrapped in a proc {} since Tcl then can optimize. For Tcl, a "map" function is discussed as a future enhancement. With this hint and further searching I found http://wiki.tcl.tk/12848

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most efficient method is this:

```
set idx 0
foreach item $theList {
    lset theList $idx [expr {$item * $item}]
    incr idx
}
```

If the list is short (e.g., a few hundred elements) the cost of allocating a new list is minimal though, so you can use this (simpler) version instead:

```
foreach item $theList {
    lappend newList [expr {$item * $item}]
}
```

Note that the `foreach` command is *only* fast if placed in a procedure (or lambda expression or method) and expressions are *only* fast if placed in `{`braces`}`. Also, **don't speculate, measure**: take care to use the `time` command to find out how fast your code really is.

Comment: And no, there's nothing shorter. There's been some preparatory work on doing a [map](http://dev.crypt.co.za/incubator/doc/tcltm/control/functional-tip.wiki) command (among others) but it's not yet got to the point of being a full proposal and for sure won't make 8.6.

Comment: With the proposed lset solution, the original list is overwritten. I still have accepted this great answer because actually the major point in speed in tcl seems to be on the statement of wrapping code in proc's or in methods. The foreach in a proc takes only 13%(!) of the time of a foreach on toplevel in the interpreter.

Comment: The comment on "don't speculate, measure" is actually at the heart of my question: I'm currently preparing a small and simple overview of speed measurements between perl/python/tcl/ruby and want to give all an equally fair chance.

Comment: Interestingly, in my measurements the lset is slower than the foreach loop. My init code for the test: -- proc fillArray {a b} { eval return \[list $a [string repeat "\[incr a\] " [incr b -$a]]\] }; set a [fillArray 1 1000000];  -- Then I have two procs which I "time": -- proc test {} { global a; set l {}; foreach i $a { lappend l "$i" } } -- versus -- proc test_lset {} { global a; set idx 0; foreach i $a { lset a $idx "$i"; incr idx } } -- 10 iterations of test take ~0.083s of test_lset 0.137s. Sorry for the quoting mess here I'm not sure if I should put this in the answer.

Comment: Ah, the backslashes in the code in the comment do not appear: fillArray comes from here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6926407/923794

Comment: The reason why putting stuff inside a procedure (or lambda) is important is because that provides a local variable table. Internally, access to the LVT is _very_ fast. However, some commands are only compiled to bytecode when an LVT is present (i.e., inside a proc). This is OK in most real code, as almost everything that's performance critical has always been placed in procedures; it's only in benchmarks that it's actually likely to be an issue. :-)

Comment: @cfi: And yes, `lappend` is very fast for short arrays as it lets CPUs work in ways that they like (plus memory is managed using intelligent algorithms), whereas `lset` tends to be slower due to cache effects… we think; this has been somewhat mystifying to the Tcl devs for a few years. OTOH, the very fastest method of all is to use the assembler built into 8.6, but that's really very experimental right now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is something shorter (using the tcllib [struct::list](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/struct_list.html) package), but not necessarily faster.

```
package require struct::list
puts [struct::list mapfor x $data { expr {$x * $x} }]
```